# Using a for loop to get the value in the dictionary

Tags: python

Agnes decides that she wants to start creating targeted advertisements for people. Here is a list of customer objects with information about their name, age, job, pet, and pet name. You'll use loops to find people that meet certain requirements for Agnes' targeted marketing. Write for loops with conditional statements in conjunction with break and continue to get the desired output.

```
people = [
    {'name': "Daniel", 'age': 29, 'job': "Engineer", 'pet': "Cat", 'pet_name': "Gato"}, 
    {'name': "Katie", 'age': 30, 'job': "Teacher", 'pet': "Dog", 'pet_name': "Frank"},
    {'name': "Owen", 'age': 26, 'job': "Sales person", 'pet': "Cat", 'pet_name': "Cosmo"},
    {'name': "Josh", 'age': 22, 'job': "Student", 'pet': "Cat", 'pet_name': "Chat"},
    {'name': "Estelle", 'age': 35, 'job': "French Diplomat", 'pet': "Dog", 'pet_name': "Gabby"},
    {'name': "Gustav", 'age': 24, 'job': "Brewer", 'pet': "Dog", 'pet_name': "Helen"}
]
```

Use a for loop to find the first person in the list of people that has a dog as their pet. The iteration count shouldn't exceed 2. In your loop add a print statement that says

```
"{first_dog_person} has a dog! Had to check {number} of records to find a dog owner."
```

what i have done:

```
first_dog_person = None
iteration_count = 0
for person in people:
    iteration_count += 1
    if iteration_count == 2:
        break
    if person['pet'] == 'Dog':
        first_dog_person = person['name'] 
        print(f"{first_dog_person} has a dog! Had to check {iteration_count} of records to find a dog owner.")
        
       
    
print (f"{first_dog_person} has a dog! Had to check {iteration_count} of records to find a dog owner.")
```

even tho this still doesnt work I still need to use the continue function

Comment: The idea is help you to solve specific problems not do your homework. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Regards.

Comment: first_dog_person = None
iteration_count = 0
for person in people:
    iteration_count += 1
    if iteration_count == 2:
        break

    
print (f"{first_dog_person} has a dog! Had to check {iteration_count} of records to find a dog owner.")

Comment: I tried multiple times but could achive the answer. I tried first_dog_person = people[person]["name] . Nothing worked thats why i came here

Comment: You should add what you've tried so far into the body of your question so contributors can better help you solve the problem (rather than solve it for you).

Comment: thank you ill do it for next time, it wasnt my intention. This is still for me to learn.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to StackOverflow. Learning how to post a well structured question is a skill all of its own, one that I'm sure you'll develop with more practice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement says that you shouldn't exceed 2 iterations. However, your code has this line:

```py
    if iteration_count == 2:
```

This condition tests if you've reached the second iteration, not if you've exceeded it. Try stepping through your code using a debugger, paying special attention to this statement as you run through the iterations.

Comment: This is a useful comment not an answer. Regards.